# Integration error Spring Boot with WSDL

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, wsdl

I am unable to resolve this issue in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <!-- tag::wsdl[] -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                <generateDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/generated-sources/wsdl</generateDirectory>
                <generatePackage>br.adv.advise.wsdl</generatePackage>
                <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <url>http://example/integracaoPublicacao.php?wsdl</url>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- end::wsdl[] -->
    </plugins>
</build>
```

> Unable to parse input schema(s). Error messages should have been provided. (org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate:default:generate-sources)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is maven-jaxb2-plugin a requirement? I have had a lot more luck generating JAXB clients from WSDLs using the Apache CXF wsdl2java plugin.

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html

Not a direct answer, but perhaps an alternative route.